# Error in updating a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

here I'm trying to display the record of a member and trying to edit the details.
First, I'm fetching the details from a database into textboxes, then, when I should hit the submit button..it should update the entry which is updated and should keep the original value of the textbox which is not updated.

Here's the code :-

The first one is of **editmember.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'dbconnector.php';
$receivedusername=$_REQUEST['username'];
$parentusername=$_SESSION['username'];
$_SESSION['cusername']=$receivedusername;
//check session
if((isset($_SESSION['logged'])) && ($_SESSION['logged']==1))
{
    //now map the user to it's parent account
    $query="select * from master_member where parentusername = '" . $parentusername . "' and currentusername = '" . $receivedusername . "'";
    $result=mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        //account mapped, green signal to proceed
        ?>
        <form action="memberaction.php?action=edit" method="post">
        <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Username : <input type="text" name="usrnm" value="<?php echo ($row['currentusername']); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>Email : <input type="text" name="eml" value="<?php echo ($row['currentemail']); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
        <?php 
    }
    else
    {
        echo "You aren't authorized to perform this task, redirecting.";
        header('refresh:2;URL=members.php');
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
    header('Location:login.php');
    exit();
}
?>
```

**memberaction.php**

```
case 'update':
        $memberusername=$_SESSION['cusername'];//username of the member, whose account is to be edited.
        $parentusername=$_SESSION['username'];//username of the parent.
        //since the account is already matched to the parent account before, we do not need to do it again.
        //get the field value
            $usrnm=(isset($_POST['usrnm'])) ? $_POST['usrnm'] : '';
            $eml=(isset($_POST['eml'])) ? $_POST['eml'] : '';
            $query="update master_member set currentusername = '" . $usrnm . "' and currentemail = '" . $eml . "' where parentusername = '" . $parentusername . "' and currentusername = '" . $memberusername . "'";
            $result=mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
            if($result)
            {
                echo "updated";
                header('refresh:2;URL=members.php');
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Errors";
            }

        break;
```

After I hit the submit button, it displays successfully updated, but no change takes place at the database.
What possible mistake I'm doing ?

My DB structure is like :-

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/969c54/2

Comment: You have `name="usrnm"` and `$cusername=$_REQUEST['username'];` so no match. And that's just "ONE" of them. Double check all your input values against your variables. You need to debug.

Comment: Hey Fred -ii- , the actual url is **editmember.php?username=somethinghere** ..so therefore I have $cusername=$_REQUEST['username'].

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are not running an UPDATE query anywhere, so no changes can ever get pushed to the database. `insert ignore` will **NOT** change an existing record. It'll only create a new one if no unique key constraints would be violated.

Comment: editmember.php?username=somethinghere';DROP%20TABLE%20master_member;--

Comment: Hey Marc B, I thought **insert ignore** would work here ?

Comment: As @MarcB says, INSERT IGNORE does exactly what it says in the tin, it will INSERT a NEW record unless a record already exists with that primary/unique key (in which case the INSERT will be IGNORED) - you possibly want something like `REPLACE INTO` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` type syntax.

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: @tadman I'll go through all the links posted by you..meanwhile, I've updated my source code a bit..could you please possibly check it for a glitch ?

Comment: Fixed it myself..apparently..**AND** is never used in a mysql update query..once should always use commas.